# Insert a Power BI report into a custom page in AL

Tags: visual-studio-code, powerbi, dynamics-business-central

I'm new in Microsoft Dynamics 365 Business Central and AL code and my boss told me that he wants to see a new page in our sandbox environment that shows a Power BI embedded on it. Is there any way to show something like the right part of the standard "Customer list" that you can select the Power BI report?

Thanks in advance

```
page 50101 "Sample Page"
{
    PageType = Card;
    ApplicationArea = All;
    UsageCategory = Lists;
}
```

This is the result that I'd like or something similar.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/R3cqq.jpg

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done this, but I believe you should be able to embed Power BI report using Control Add-In.

> The control add-in object allows you to add custom functionality to Dynamics 365 Business Central. A control add-in is a custom control, or visual element, for displaying and modifying data within an iframe or a page. For example, a control add-in can display the content of a webpage, visualize data as a chart or on a map, or host a custom web application.

Reference:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/business-central/dev-itpro/developer/devenv-control-addin-object

See this Youtube video for a brief demo
[How do I add a Custom Control? | Dynamics 365 Business Central](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AnKdrW5ILo0)